# Setting up the optimal IDE/Toolchain on Linux for D Language

Tags: d

So, I have this on again/off again relationship with D. I'm back at it again, on a new machine. First things first, setting the toolchain.

I think I'll go again with Eclipse + DDT, but [last encounter didn't go that well](http://forum.dlang.org/post/guzqormlskvvynwbxhrk@forum.dlang.org) and I may use some guidance before I install stuffs ...

First, for some reasons I'd like to stay on Linux, but I may as well move to Windows. Do you guys have an articulated opinion as to which OS is more suitable for D development ?

Second, I am not (yet) a hard-core coder, so the more integrated the development environment, the better. Is the current version of Eclipse + DDT really usable  ? What about Code::Blocks ? Anything else ?

Third, debugging. I'd really appreciate a debugger that enables step-by-step through source code, that sort of niceties ... I understand GDB works nice, but would there be something more user-friendly ?

Thxxxxx

Answer (score 2):

Try monodevelop with [mono-d](http://wiki.dlang.org/Mono-D). It works ok for me. Autocompletion is almost perfect, speed is very good and debugging works too. DDT works OK too, but autocompletion is not so perfect.

Answer (score 2):

I would also suggest MonoDevelop with [Mono-D plugin](http://wiki.dlang.org/Mono-D) installed.

No matter how I love Mono-D, every now and then I have a problem with MonoDevelop (Xamarin Studio). - Not because of Mono-D, but because Xamarin constantly breaks the API it seems...

DDT is a very good alternative.

Before these two, I used Code::Blocks which had pretty nice D integration. I did not check the state of it lately.

Finally, you always have [VisualD](http://rainers.github.io/visuald/visuald/StartPage.html) as a very good option if you are a Windows user. In fact, if you use Windows, this is your best option, in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Mono-D. Although the debugger is not that good, and using it with an AMD card with factory drivers may result in [missing editor tab captions](http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Editor-show-no-filename-on-tabs-td4661464.html). Installing unstable versions help, but it may break other things like refactoring with 5.3. But it's mutch better than Eclipse by my opinion, and handles GDC and LDC toolchains flawlessly.